# How do 2D arrays and deepToString work?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class main {

    public static void main (String[] args ) {
        int rand = (int)Math.random()*17;
        int[][] output = array(rand);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
    }


    public static int[][] array(int n)  { //btw n is y/height
        int x = (int)Math.pow(2, n-1); //# of col
        int max = (int)Math.pow(2, n) - 1;

        int [][] out = new int[n][x];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                out[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * (max + 1));
            }
        }
        return out;

    }
}
```

I'm learning how to code and a cousin gave me their old laptop and I found some small java files here and there. This one is called "itsmagic.java" but I don't really understand what the purpose is?

From what I understand it seems that we are creating a 2D array of some sort and then what? I understand that `deepToString` is supposed to be used to convert multidimensional arrays to strings, but how does that work? Why is it commented out?

Comment: Maybe your cousin didn't want to print the array to the console? Ask him/her [deepToString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: He was probably just using the `System.out.println()` for testing, it does nothing to the array, it merely prints to your console.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your code is:

-Pick a random int n from 0 to 17.

-setting a x = 2^(n-1)

-setting a max= 2^n

-Creating a double entry tab dimensions n*x

-Filling each case with a random number between 0 and max

**So the result is a double entry tab of dimensions [0 to 17][2^(0 to 16)] filled with numbers between 0 and 2^(0 to 17)**

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.deepToString() is used for either single or multidimensional arrays, it's usually used for multidimensional arrays as it can clearly output each array.

You will be able to output both the first and second array of "output" in your example.

If you run a test and add in the array manually, you will see it prints both the arrays together instead of showing just the first dimension.